# SignalR send object - newbie

Tags: signalr

With Signal R, if trying to send an object, what is the syntax to pass the model?

```
private async void FormLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Connection stuff...
    Proxy.On("sendHello", () => OnSendDataConnection(ModelBuilder()));
}

private void OnSendDataConnection(ConnectionModel model)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,model?????)
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(LoadW));
}
```

Comment: This question does not look like a SignalR question at all. If I understand correctly, your problem is just how to dispatch to the WPF main thread, and you already receive your `ConnectionModel` correctly, right? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: look at this example..https://github.com/dstpierre/lcsk will help for you..also you need to specify more information about this question.beacause i con't understand what is your need.this solution is my assemption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the question (text, and not the code) I understand you are trying to send Complex object to JS side and use it there? Is that correct?

In that case the solution is supposed to be simple:

From the [ASP.NET.SignalR site](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server):

> You can specify a return type and parameters, including complex types
>   and arrays, as you would in any C# method. Any data that you receive
>   in parameters or return to the caller is communicated between the
>   client and the server by using JSON, and **SignalR handles the binding
>   of complex objects and arrays of objects automatically**.

Example C#:

```cs
    public void SendMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addContosoChatMessageToPage(new ContosoChatMessage() { UserName = name, Message = message });
    }
```

JS:

```js
    var contosoChatHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub;
    contosoChatHubProxy.client.addMessageToPage = function (message) {
        console.log(message.UserName + ' ' + message.Message);
    });
```

Where ContosoChatMessage is:

```cs
   public class ContosoChatMessage
   {
       public string UserName { get; set; }
       public string Message { get; set; }
   }
```

*(read on for examples...)*

So basically, in JS once 'model' received, you should be able to use 'model.XY', where XY is a member of the model complex object.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to convert my fields to properties, otherwise, it doesn't send the information properly.
From

```
public string myField;
```

to

```
public string myField {get; set;}
```